# LUCENE_40 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, lucene

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
```

I am runing lucene search code and I am getting an error in above line saying

```
LUCENE_40 cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I am using lucene 5.1.0 version.

---

I have removed the `version.LUCENE_40`  from the standard analyzer parameters, so now there's no error in the code but when I run the code, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: HelloLucene. Program will exit.
```

Here's the code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;   
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

import java.io.IOException;


public class HelloLucene {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
        addDoc(w, "Lucene in Action", "193398817");
        addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
        addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
        addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
        w.close();
        String querystr = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "lucene";    
        Query q = new QueryParser("title", analyzer).parse(querystr);
        int hitsPerPage = 10;
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage);
        searcher.search(q, collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
        System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
        for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
            int docId = hits[i].doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("isbn") + "\t" +  d.get("title"));
        }

        reader.close();
    }

    private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn)  throws IOException {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));

        doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
        w.addDocument(doc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  Check your classpath, and make sure that *all* lucene jars are version 5.1.  If you have any older lucene jars, make sure they are removed from the classpath, and replaced with the latest version.  It sounds like you may have lucene-core at version 5.1, but analyzers-common at an earlier version.  Or maybe vice-versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, like it says, `Version.LUCENE_40` [doesn't exist](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.html).  `Lucene_4_0` does, but that will only bring you to the next problem:

[`StandardAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) no longer takes a version argument.  Just use:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

Comment: thanks ... now there is not even a single error in program however when i execute code i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0